# JavaScript this is global object inside of prototype method

Tags: javascript

I have a class that does some pretty complicated things. For this example, I've simplified it a ton to the following:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

MyClass.prototype.sayName = function (cb) {
    return this.getName(cb);
};
MyClass.prototype.getName = function (cb) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("My name is " + this.name);
        cb();
    }, 1000);
};
```

Now of course there is no need for async code in this example, but in the actual example there is async code (ex. network requests). I just simplified it to make it easier for this question. Also, this actual class is part of a 3rd party package, so I don't really have any control over it.

Anyways, I have the following code that works **perfectly**:

```
const myInstance = new MyClass("Bob");
myInstance.sayName(() => {
    console.log("Done");
});
```

What I'm trying to do to make it more consistent in my code, is build a wrapper that converts those callbacks into promises:

```
const myInstance = new MyClass("Bob");
const standard = () => {
    return getPromise(myInstance.sayName);
};
standard();
function getPromise(func) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        func(function() {
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

Problem is. That code doesn't work. I get the following error:

> (node:58910) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.getName is not a function

It looks like inside of the `sayName` method in that second example `this` is referring to the global object, and not the instance of MyClass.

Why doesn't this code work? And why is `this` something else when I try to use it inside of a wrapper?

Comment: @Quentin not quite sure how that is a duplicate. `myInstance` is the same in the wrapper as outside the wrapper. And `sayName` doesn't have any inner functions.

Comment: You are passing `myInstance.sayName` as a callback. Inside `sayName` you are using `this`. The value of `this` is not the value you want. Therefore you want to know how to access the correct 'this' inside the callback. Which is what the duplicate question is all about.